# What does "s." and "n" mean/do in this mysql statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a project that requires me look at someone elses code, i'm still new to some of this stuff and there is something that I dont quite understand so was hoping someone could shed some light on what the code is actually doing or what it means?

Here is the statement in question:

```
select s.* from $tableA n, $tableB s where
            n.id='$send' and
            n.status='$status' and
            n.field=s.id";
```

I understand that down to basics this statement is getting all of the fields from tableA and tableB im just unsure what the `s.` does or what the `n` does in this statement? are they simply there as identifiers or am I completely wrong in this manner? I am happy to provide more information if it is necessary.

Comment: They're  [aliases](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+table+alias&oq=mysql+table+alias&aqs=chrome..69i57.3431j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll go and do some research into these then! thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called `SQL Table Aliases` and are basically temporary names which you give to the tables in order to have better readability when you use the table names to specify a column.

In your example

```
SELECT s.* FROM $tableA n, $tableB s
WHERE  n.id='$send'
       AND n.status='$status'
       AND n.field=s.id ;
```

is the same as

```
SELECT $tableB.* FROM $tableA, $tableB
WHERE  $tableA.id='$send'
       AND $tableA.status = '$status'
       AND $tableA.field = $tableB.id ;
```

but obviously it's easier to read.

The table aliases are even more useful when you join more tables and are absolutely a must when you make self joins.

### Syntax note:

You may or you may not use the `AS` keyword when alias a table.

```
SELECT table_name AS alias
```

is the same as

```
SELECT table_name alias
```

and although it's longer sometimes it leads to a better readability (for example in a large and messy query the big `AS` is easier to spot :)

Comment: I'd also point out that they are essential if you are joining to a table you have already used in order to differentiate the two.

Comment: especially/crucial for self joins